# Regenerating a binary image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I have a binary image `Im1`

[image]

I want to regenerate the same image using the indexes of the white pixels.

First I created another image `Im2`:

```
Im2 = zeros(size(Im1,1),size(Im1,2));
```

Then I extracted the indexes of the white pixels using *find*:

```
[r , c] = find(Im1 == 1);
```

Finally I substitutes the `r` and `c` into `Im2` to regenerate `Im1`:

```
Im2(r,c) = 1;
```

The problem is the regenerated image looks different:

[image]

What is the explanation of having square instead of original shape of the object in `Im1`??

and how to regenerate `Im1` based only on indexes of the non zero pixels???

**Note:** when I used the following code:

```
for j = 1:length(r)
Im2(r(j,1),c(j,1)) = 1;
end
```

`Im2` regenerated correctly!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/): either convert your row and column indices to linear

```
ind = sub2ind(size(Im2), r,c);
Im2(ind) = 1;
```

or directly extract the indices as linear:

```
ind = find(Im1 == 1);
%// ...
Im2(ind) = 1;
```

Another approach is to use (linear-)[logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
ind = Im1==1;
Im2(ind) = 1;
```

In your code as it stands, `Im2(r,c)` refers to all combinations (Cartesian product) of one value from `r` and one value from `c`; which is not what you want. Linear indexing (or linear-logical indexing) avoids that, matching only one value from `r` with one value from `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with indexing in Matlab.

If you access something as `Img(values,values2)`that will take conbinations of pair values as @LuisMendo correctly explained in the comments

If you want to select specific random indexes, the best thing is to use linear indexes:

```
indexes=sub2ind(size(Img),r,c);
Img(indexes)=1;
```

Comment: Just a small correction: `Img(values,values2)` doesn't take from min to max; rather, it takes all combinations of one value from `values` and one from `values2`